# SED : replace part of syntax to lower case

Tags: linux, sed

Original Text file:
.ABC0    (ABC0),
.EFG2    (EFG2),
.ZZZ3    (ZZZ3),

How to convert this part to

.ABC0    (abc0),
.EFG2    (efg2),
.ZZZ3    (zzz3),

with SED command easily?

There's issue to make it work.

```
echo ".ABC(ABC)," | sed -e 's/\(.*\.[A-Z]*\(\)\([A-Z]*\)\)/\1\L\2\E/ p'
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

```
sed -e 's/\(\.[A-Z0-9]*\)\( ([A-Z0-9]*)\)/\1\L\2\E/g'
```

- Remove the `.*` from the beginning, it matches as much as it can, i.e. it skips to the last occurrence of the pattern.
- Include the digits in the character classes.
- Use `(` without a backslash to match a parenthesis literally.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/([^)]*)/\L&/g' file
```

Replace the contents of parenthesis by its lowercase equivalent.